# SimpleCV NameError: name 'images' is not defined

Tags: python, opencv, simplecv

I try Library SimpleCV. I have Ubuntu 11.10, Python 2.7 with PIL (python-imaging ver. 1.1.7-3ubuntu1)

According to Install instructions I downloaded SimpleCV_1.1_linux_all.deb package. Then I install:
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy.

Since Ubuntu 11.10 has python-opencv library I don't install any other opencv library (I dont upgrade from OpenCV 2.1 to OpenCV 2.3) library. Then I installed SimpleCV_1.1_linux_all.deb package. It installed to /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SimpleCV. I try test this library and have problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from SimpleCV import *

my_image = Image(images/redeye.jpg)<br>
my_image.show()
```

it shows error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./simplecvimg.py", line 6, in 
>       my_image = Image(images/redeye.jpg)
>   NameError: name 'images' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `images/redeye.jpg` as a string: `Image("images/redeye.jpg")`.

```
my_image = Image("images/redeye.jpg")
```

You are currently passing that literally to the `Image()` class, hence why python is intepreting it as a variable, and as such, raising a `NameError` exception because the `images` local or global name is not found.

Comment: @marinex: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept an answer if it's helped and worked for you. It will also get rid of it from the 'unanswered' section!