# NameError: name 'image' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, jupyter-notebook, classification

I am getting the error in the post title when I attempt to run a pretrained MobileNet classification. The image I am using to run the script is located in my 'MobileNet-inference-images/American_Cam.jpg directory.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Here is my script, my environment, the error traceback, and what have investigated so far.

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Model
from keras.applications import imagenet_utils
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

mobile =keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet()

def prepare_image(file):
    img_path = 'MobileNet-inference-images/'
    img = image.load_img(img_path + file, target_size=(224, 224))
    img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array_expanded_dims = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
    return 
    keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_imput(img_array_expanded_dims)

preprocessed_image = prepare_image('MobileNet-inference-images/American_Cam.jpg')
predictions = mobile.predict(preprocessed_image)
results = imagenet_utils.decode_predictions(predictions)
results
```

I am running python 3.6.1 in an Anaconda "custom" environment (64 bit) in a Juypter notebook.

The traceback is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-90b9684f2691> in <module>()
----> 1 preprocessed_image = prepare_image('MobileNet-inference-images/American_Cam.jpg')
      2 predictions = mobile.predict(preprocessed_image)
      3 results = imagenet_utils.decode_predictions(predictions)
      4 results

<ipython-input-32-c204346d1e63> in prepare_image(file)
      1 def prepare_image(file):
      2     img_path = 'MobileNet-inference-images/'
----> 3     img = image.load_img(img_path + file, target_size=(224, 224))
      4     img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
      5     img_array_expanded_dims = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)

NameError: name 'image' is not defined
```

I have seen an error of the same name [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482897/simplecv-nameerror-name-images-is-not-defined), but that appears to be a separate issue(as I am enclosing my image path). [Other posts](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/166418-python-image-manipulation/) have suggested an issue with PIL. But if I test is PIL is operating with a simple script(such as below), I don't get a PIL error.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('MobileNet-inference-images/American_Cam.jpg')
im.show()
```

Comment: You might want to import `load_img` as you have imported `ImageDataGenerator` and use it directly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

from `image` you import only `ImageDataGenerator` but you also need other attributes,
better change it

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

to

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
# and use 
# image.ImageDataGenerator()
# image.load_img()
```